# Non-trivial usages of tikz foreach with a list of coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm struggling to make the following code work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \point in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)} {
    \begin{scope}[shift={\point}]
        \fill (0,0) circle (0.1) ;
    \end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The log contains

> Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.
>
> See the tikz package documentation for explanation. Type  H 
> for immediate help.  ...
> l.11 }
> This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot:
> Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method.
>
> Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!

Is there a way to make use of these coordinates directly, or should I resort to the X/Y style?

Update: (to address the claim that () solves the problem).
I have fully updated the Miktex installation through console. However, the following lines (directly connected to the usage of shift + ()) still appear:

> File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for
> MiKTeX ))
>
> Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
>
> Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
>
> [1]

Exactly one brace for each coordinate in the list (checked with a different number of points).

Comment: it works with `[shift={(\point)}]` >>> `( )` is added

Comment: I agree that it partially works. However, it still complains on the bunch of `Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!`. So, I supposed this is not the solution.

Comment: Do you have an updated MikTeX? `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \point in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)}
\fill[shift={(\point)}] (0,0) circle (0.1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Your error has nothing with `\foreach` loop. After correcting error in MWE, as pointed  @Black Mild in his comment, your MWE works fine (no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes.  I tested with recent MiKTeX bundle. SO, it seems that your installation of LaTeX is outdated.

Comment: @Zarko, Unfortunately, the issue is still present. I'm on updated Miktex Windows installation

Comment: Instead of `minimal` try to use `article` or `standalone` document class. However, it seems that you haven't loaded fonts you needed. Sorry, we cant see, how your MiKTeX is loaded and configured. For sure your corrected MWE (see @BlackMild comment) works fine, as I said in my comment above. Try to test it as it is in see if you still get warnings.

Comment: `\expanded{\noexpand\begin{scope}[shift={\point}]}` works for me…

Comment: @egreg, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When the TikZ parser (which is also used to parse the `shift` coordinate) finds something it doesn't understand, it usually tries to expand what's in front of it.

This is why

```
\fill \point circle (0.1);
```

works without a hitch.

In case the user writes wrong syntax TikZ has a fail-safe as it decrements an internal counter and only tries the expansion tactic until this counter reaches 0.
This counter start usually at 100 and gets decremted by 1 or 10 depending on the case.

At certain places, this counter is reset to 100, for example at the start of a path (which is why

```
\fill[shift=\point] (0,0) circle (0.1) ;
```

works) or when the parser successfully finds a valid path specification.
It **does not get reset** at the start of the picture or at the start of a scope. And since it is still the default and initialized-with 0 at that point, the parsing throws an error.

Using `shift=(\point)` works because there is another expansion of everything happening but it will lead to warnings of

```
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
```

This is because it now tries to parse

```
((0,0))
```

and what happens is that the parser recognizes `(0` as the *x* value for the coordinate and the second `0` as the *y* value. But it leaves the very last `)` on the TeX input stream, similar as if you would have done:

```
\path;
Foo
\path;
```

Now, why doesn't `(0` raise any errors? As with many things in PGF/TikZ this will be fed to PGFmath and evaluated … and PGFmath doesn't have a problem with it. Try

```
\pgfmathparse{(((((1}\pgfmathresult
```

or even

```
\pgfmathparse{1))))}\pgfmathresult
```

Instead of using `\expanded` and `\noexpand` as suggested in the comments I'd recommend using the **`.expanded` key handler** which will instruct PGFkeys to expand the value before given it to the key.

(Or we patch either the `scope` environment or the `shift` key or just manually reset the counter but using the key handler works always in other places very well when TikZ does no expansion on its own.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \point in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)} {
  \begin{scope}[shift/.expanded=\point]
    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=.1];
  \end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```