# How to set up a sequence of clips in TiKZ with a loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, scoping, path-clipping

Here's the simplest file I can think of which demonstrates my problem: I simply want to draw two circles, half filled:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)}
  {
    \draw \x circle[radius = 1];
    \begin{scope}[shift = \x]
      \draw[clip] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
      \fill[black!50] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,0);
    \end{scope};
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see if you run this, only the first circle is half filled.  And I get a lot of errors:

```
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ) in font nullfont!
```

I'm a bit mystified by this, as I've never had this sort of error before.

I *should* say that although this particular problem could be solved easily by other means, it is really the simplest case of a more general diagram, which will consist (I hope) of lots of circles all filled to different depths.

I've tried putting brackets around `\x`; I've tried leaving out the shift parameter and using coordinate transformations, as in

```
\fill[black!50] \x + (-1,-1) rectangle \x + (1,0);
```

but that doesn't work either.  (In fact the latter is even worse, as it only gives me the first circle one quarter filled.)

Any advice would be very warmly received!

Comment: You need `\x` to be expanded: `\begin{scope}[shift/.expanded = \x]`. Same problem and solution as [Q643948](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655530). With your last snippet, you could just use relative coordinates: `\fill[black!50] \x ++ (-1,-1) rectangle + (2,0);`

Comment: No `;` after `\end{scope}` by the way.

Answer (score 4):

No image added, so I try this one:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,2}
        {
            \draw (\x,0) circle(1);
            \fill (\x+1,0) arc(0:-180:1);
        }  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to take care of the different ways Ti*k*Z parses and expands the input. It seems that in different contexts, things are not expanded as might be expected.

For example, while this works (thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for the hint):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)} {
    \begin{scope}
        \draw[clip] \x circle[radius = 1];
        \fill[black!50] \x ++(-1,-1) rectangle +(2,1);
    \end{scope}
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This does not:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)} {
    \coordinate (x) at \x;
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(x)}]
        \draw[clip] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
        \fill[black!50] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,0);
    \end{scope}
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Nor does this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)} {
    \coordinate (x) at \x;
    \draw (x) circle[radius = 1];
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

So, the safest way to do this is probably still like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {{0,0}, {2,0}} {
    \draw (\x) circle[radius = 1];
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(\x)}]
      \draw[clip] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
      \fill[black!50] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,0);
    \end{scope}
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that while `at` as keyword (as in `\coordinate (x) at ...`) only likes explicit coordinates, using `at` as option should work here (at least with a current version of Ti*k*Z). So a variation of the above would be:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)} {
    \coordinate[at=\x] (x);
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(x)}]
        \draw[clip] (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
        \fill[black!50] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,0);
    \end{scope}
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks - so that was my error!  I've used lists of coordinates before, but here, as you point out, there are subtleties of parsing to be considered.  That works perfectly.

Comment: Well, I am not fully sure about the parsing mechanism, but I think the problem is that, on the one hand, you need to mask the comma, so you need to write `{(0,0)}`, but you can't say `\coordinate (c) at {(0,0)}`.

Comment: You don't need to mask a `(x,y)` notation as the first variable for a PGFFor list, it detects the `(` and grabs until the next `)`. At least with an uptodate PGF. (Of course, your code here doesn't have the `(` anymore and then the `{}` are necessary.) The problem comes from the `shift` at the `scope` which doesn't try to expand the argument as it would on a path. The expansion counter isn't set up correctly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I see. I also discovered that the `shift` context somehow seems to parse things differently. I was able to pass `(0,0)` as `\x` to `\coordinate (c) at \x;`, but later on using `(c)` didn't really work.

Comment: `coordinate at …` is a “quick” version of `node[shape=coordinate] at …` but doesn't parse the `at` part like a node. [It requires explicit `(…)`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701388) Yes, TikZ can be finicky about things. It already expands a lot of things at various places but they haven't thought of everything.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah, thanks! I just found that using the `at` option works! Nice!

Answer (score 3):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)}{
  \tikzset{shift/.expanded = \x} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655530/16595
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
    \fill[black!50] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,0);
  \end{scope}
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius = 1];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)}
    \draw \x circle[radius=1] [
      path picture={
        \fill[black!50] (path picture bounding box.south west)
              rectangle (path picture bounding box.east);}];

\tikz
  \foreach \x in {(0,0), (2,0)}
    \draw[shift=\x] (0,0) circle[radius=1] [
      path picture={\fill[black!50] (-1,-1) rectangle +(2,1);}];
\end{document}
```